# Azure Graph API: authorize application on multiple tenants

Tags: azure, oauth, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365

I am trying to create an application to browse my contacts directory on Exchange.
I have set up everything and I am able request the authorization from my app.
I can present the modal view, enter the login information, retrieve the token, but when I try to authorize the app with the same account I have created it I get this message:

```
The client <my app id> and resource <my app URI> identify the same application.
```

If I try to authorize another account, I receive this message instead:

```
User account <an email> from external identity provider <a url> is not
supported for application <my app id>
```

If I try to login on the [Graph Explorer Console](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/) or on the [Office 365 OAuth Sandbox](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net), they work fine with the second address, but not with the first one.

I am really confuse. I feel like I have mess up some configuration option, but I don't really understand which one.

Comment: Regarding #1, can you please check if you're passing the `App ID` of your application for `resource` querystring parameter and authenticating/authorizing against your tenant URL (instead of generic URL)? I had the same issue which I solved by passing `https://graph.windows.net` for resource instead of `App ID`.

Comment: I am passing the `App ID URI` as described in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx)

Comment: I did the same thing as well :). Try this project: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet and see the sign-in URL sent to Azure AD. Contd.

Comment: Based on this, I used this URL: `var signInUrl = String.Format(
                "https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/authorize?response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&client_id={1}&resource={2}&redirect_uri={3}&state={4}&nonce={5}",
                Uri.EscapeDataString(tenantId),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString("https://graph.windows.net"),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(state), {random-nonce})
                 );` and things worked for me.

Comment: Man, I wish I could buy you a beer! Please add your solution as answer, and I will be glad to accept it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding #1, please do not pass `App ID` of your application for `resource` querystring parameter when authenticating against your tenant URL. I ran into the exact same problem.

Then I ran [`WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet`](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet) from Github and noted down the sign-in URL it created and I used the following:

```
var signInUrl = String.Format(
                "https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/authorize?response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&client_id={1}&resource={2}&redirect_uri={3}&state={4}&nonce={5}",
                Uri.EscapeDataString(tenantId),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString("https://graph.windows.net"),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(state),
                 string.Format("{0}{1}", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks, Guid.NewGuid().Stringify())
                 );
```

Basically I used `https://graph.windows.net` instead of `App ID` and magically things started to work :).

Another thing you could try (and I have not tried it) is authenticating against common endpoint `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize` and provide your `App ID` for the `resource` querystring.

Comment: I am able to get the token, but all my requests to the Graph API always receive 401 error: any other hint? I am using the REST API with Javascript.

Comment: I am following what is specified in the `Use the Access Token to Access the Resource` section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx), but I keep receiving 401 error. I have also tried to test everything with a REST Client, but I get `Invalid domain name in the request url`.

Comment: I would actually recommend seeing the samples on Github.